# Improve insert performance when checking existing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this simple query that inserts rows from one table(`sn_users_main`) into another(`sn_users_history`).

To make sure `sn_users_history` only has unique rows it checks if the column `query_time` already exists and if it does then don't insert. `query_time` is kind of a session identifier that is the same for every row in `sn_users_main`.

This works fine but since `sn_users_history` is reaching 50k rows running this query takes more than 2 minutes to run which is too much. Is there anything I can do to improve performance and get the same result?

```
INSERT INTO sn_users_history(query_time,user_id,sn_name,sn_email,sn_manager,sn_active,sn_updated_on,sn_last_Login_time,sn_is_vip,sn_created_on,sn_is_team_lead,sn_company,sn_department,sn_division,sn_role,sn_employee_profile,sn_location,sn_employee_type,sn_workstation) --- Columns of history table
    SELECT snm.query_time,
            snm.user_id,
            snm.sn_name,
            snm.sn_email,
            snm.sn_manager,
            snm.sn_active,
            snm.sn_updated_on,
            snm.sn_last_Login_time,
            snm.sn_is_vip,
            snm.sn_created_on,
            snm.sn_is_team_lead,
            snm.sn_company,
            snm.sn_department,
            snm.sn_division,
            snm.sn_role,
            snm.sn_employee_profile,
            snm.sn_location,
            snm.sn_employee_type,
            snm.sn_workstation
    ---Columns of main table
    FROM sn_users_main snm
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT snh.query_time
    FROM sn_users_history snh
    WHERE snh.query_time = snm.query_time) --Dont insert items into history table if they already exist
```

Comment: Create an index on `sn_users_history( query_time )`

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ is the place to start with most performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing extra condition on user_id, when you are inserting into history table. You have to check combination of userid, querytime.

For your question, I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel. SQL Server is already having temporal tables, to suppor this historical data holding. [Read about SQL Server Temporal Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you want to still continue with this approach, I would suggest you to do in batches:

1. Create a configuration Table to hold the last processed querytime

```sql
CREATE TABLE HistoryConfig(HistoryConfigId int, HistoryTableName SYSNAME,     
lastProcessedQueryTime DATETIME)
```

2. you can do incremental historical inserts

```sql
DECLARE @lastProcessedQueryTime DATETIME = (SELECT MAX(lastProcessedQueryTime) FROM HistoryConfig)
INSERT INTO sn_users_history(query_time,user_id,sn_name,sn_email,sn_manager,sn_active,sn_updated_on,sn_last_Login_time,sn_is_vip,sn_created_on,sn_is_team_lead,sn_company,sn_department,sn_division,sn_role,sn_employee_profile,sn_location,sn_employee_type,sn_workstation) --- Columns of history table
    SELECT snm.query_time,
            snm.user_id,
            snm.sn_name,
            snm.sn_email,
            snm.sn_manager,
            snm.sn_active,
            snm.sn_updated_on,
            snm.sn_last_Login_time,
            snm.sn_is_vip,
            snm.sn_created_on,
            snm.sn_is_team_lead,
            snm.sn_company,
            snm.sn_department,
            snm.sn_division,
            snm.sn_role,
            snm.sn_employee_profile,
            snm.sn_location,
            snm.sn_employee_type,
            snm.sn_workstation
    ---Columns of main table
    FROM sn_users_main snm
    WHERE query_time > @lastProcessedQueryTime
```

3. Now, you can update the configuration again

```sql
UPDATE HistoryConfig SET lastProcessedQueryTime = (SELECT MAX(lastProcessedQueryTime) FROM HistoryConfig)
HistoryTableName = 'sn_users_history'
```

I would suggest you to create index on clustered index on UserId, Query_Time(if possible, Otherwise create non-clustered index) which will improve the performance.

Other approaches you can think of:

1. Create clustered index on userId, querytime in the historical table and also have userid,querytime as clustered index on the main table and perform MERGE operation.